# Unable to run tests using Test package in flutter, Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I have created a new flutter project and added the test package into my pubspec.yaml. Everytime I try to run my test, it fails with an error.

Here is the error message:
[image]

Here is the test code i'm trying to run:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

import 'package:boringapp/main.dart';

void main() {
  testWidgets('Clicking on tile expands it', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await tester.pumpWidget(MyApp());

    expect(find.byIcon(Icons.launch), findsNothing);

    await tester.tap(find.byType(ExpansionTile));
    await tester.pump();

    expect(find.byIcon(Icons.launch), findsOneWidget);
  });
}
```

Here is my pubspec.yaml

```
name: boringapp
description: A new Flutter application.

publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  url_launcher: ^5.4.11

dev_dependencies:
  test: 1.14.7
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Here is my flutter doctor:
[image]

I am not even able to run the default test which comes when you create a new project. What am I missing?

Here is my homescreen.dart file

```
import 'package:boringapp/src/article.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  List<Article> _articles = aritcles;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Home Page'),
      ),
      body: RefreshIndicator(
        onRefresh: () async {
          setState(() {
            _articles.removeAt(0);
          });
          return;
        },
        child: ListView(
          children: _articles
              .map((item) => ExpansionTile(
                    title: Text(item.title),
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                        children: [
                          Text("comments"),
                          IconButton(
                            icon: Icon(Icons.open_in_new),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (await canLaunch(item.url)) {
                                launch(item.url);
                              }
                            },
                          )
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: There is unahndled exception of WebSocket - do you  use it in widget? Could you show boringapp/main.dart?

Comment: @SergeySalnikov here is my main.dart.
`import 'package:boringapp/screens/homeScreen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomeScreen(),
    );
  }
}
`

Comment: ok, there is nothing special^ please update your question with contents of `homeScreen`

Comment: @SergeySalnikov I have added the homescreen.dart file. Also, I tried creating a brand new project, add test package into dev dependency, and tried to run the test. It was throwing the following error: `The Flutter SDK is not available.`. Idk if this is related in anyway.

Comment: @SergeySalnikov also, do I need to be running the app in my AVD to run the test?

Comment: ok, let's move step by step ti find out where is the problem

Comment: create new project `flutter create test1` & run default test there `flutter test`. What is result?

Comment: @SergeySalnikov when I run `flutter test` it runs successfully. But when I `right click` on my `test` folder, and click on `Run 'tests in [project_name]`, it throws me the `websocket error`